# return list called from one class into another

Tags: java

i am new to java, and would like some advice on the following

i have two files:

SongsList.java and SongsMenu.java

SongsMenu.java (http://pastie.org/private/cm0zpembkqnfjif0pgdadq) lines 38 / 39

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class SongsMenu {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

...

switch (listMenuItem) {
case 1:
System.out.println("Album");
SongsList sl = new SongsList();
System.out.println(sl);
    break;
```

and SongsList.java (http://pastie.org/private/qljonhfdronvbq4ahcqgmq)

```
public class SongsList {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // reads the file and returns a list of my Music.txt file
    ...
```

when i run the SongsList, i get:

```
 $java SongsList
 Track 58                   Reggae  1637918 81          58  59      18/02/2010 21:02    28/01/2012 14:07    160 44100       MPEG audio file                             khinester:Users:khinester:Music:iTunes:iTunes Music:Unknown Artist:Unknown Album:58 Track 58.mp3
 Track 59                   Reggae  4239191 211         59  59      18/02/2010 21:02    28/01/2012 14:07    160 44100       MPEG audio file                             khinester:Users:khinester:Music:iTunes:iTunes Music:Unknown Artist:Unknown Album:59 Track 59.mp3

 ...
```

but when i run the SongsMenu

```
$java SongsMenu
  1) Album
  ...

1
Album
SongsList@50ef5502
```

How do i return the list, instead of 'SongsList@50ef5502' i would like to ultimately be able to list this in order of Album, Name  and make searches.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
::line number 39 System.out.println(sl);
```

If you try to print an object, it will only print the hashcode of the given object.

Better rewrite the program as further explained:

You can move you logic into a method and explictly call the method (or move the logic into default contructor), for example:

`Songlist` Class should be like this:

```
public class SongsList {
    public SongsList(){
        runMyCode();
    }
    public void runMyCode(){
        // SongList logic here
    }
}
```

And call songlist in songsmenu like this:

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("Album");
    SongsList sl = new SongsList();
    s1.runMyCode();
    // do something...
        break;
```

Hope this will help you. Better learn some OOP concepts buddy... It is bad to have doubts in such a basic Java code.
Try to learn java from Head first java book: [Head First Java.pdf](http://heyook.com/download/lin/EBooks/Head%20First/Head%20First%20Java%202nd%20edition.pdf)

It is quite simple and fun to learn it.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me rewriting your answer, as it was practically unreadable.

Comment: thanks for your input, i will have to read up on OOP and java.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use println on a whole object, you need to implement a toString() method in that object.
So, if you want to do this:

```
SongsList sl = new SongsList();
System.out.println(sl);
```

The class SongsList need to override the toString method:

```
public class SongsList {

public String toString(){
   String str;
   //build a string using input from your textfile
   return str;
    }
```

else it will only print a refrence to the object which is not what you want

Comment: where do i put the 'return str' in my block? as i have a 'try' //check to see if file exists exception, then i build my list. i added this on line 112, but i get an error when running the code : 'missing return statement'

Comment: you put the return str; last in the method, like you always do when returning stuff from a metod. "Missing return statement error" is because you're probably returning str inside a loop or if condition. You have to decide what you want to return if the file would for some reason be missing. One way would be to just initiate str as "String str=""; which will be an empty string. If file does not exist, the building of the string (inside the condition) will not be run and it will return an empty string, but if the file exist, the string will be built.

Answer (score 1):

I'd refactor the code to something like this:

```
class Song {
  private String title:
  private int durationInSeconds;
  ... //additional attributes as well as getters/setters
}

class Album {
  private String name;
  private String singer;
  private List<Song> songs;
  ... //additional attributes as well as getters/setters
}
```

To print an album, you could then print its name, the singer and other attributes and then iterate over the list of songs and print those as well.

You could override `toString()` for this, but if you want to have multiple layouts, e.g. song title only vs. song title plus duration, you need some other code to print that. And according to the single responsibility principle you should not put the printing code into the data classes, i.e.  `Album` or `Song`.

Example:

```
class SongsPrinter {
  public static void printSongs(List<Album> albums) {
    for( Album album : albums) {
      System.out.println( album.getName() );
      for( Song song : album.getSongs() ) {
        System.out.println("- " + song.getTitle());  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
List<Album> albums = ... ; //create and fill as you like

SongsPrinter.printSongs(albums);
```

Comment: i will try to re-write it as suggested and come back with more questions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() menthod in your SongsList class and write the logic to print all the values avaialable in it. toString() method is avaialable in Object class which is super class of allthe classes. You can ovveride toString() method to achieve ur task.